# Adding own items into QGIS 3.10 news feed?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

Is there a possibility of adding own items into the news feed of QGIS 3.10? As a GIS administrator it would be a great tool to spread GIS/QGIS related news to internal colleagues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can. I'd have to get your service to return this structure.

https://feed.qgis.org/

And with this I should be able to add your news channel.

```
url ="https://feed.qgis.org/"
text = "QGIS"
mNewsFeedParser = QgsNewsFeedParser(QUrl(url), text)
mNewsFeedModel = QgsNewsFeedProxyModel( mNewsFeedParser );
mNewsFeedParser.fetch()
```

I think you can, but I'm not completely sure.
Anyway, the welcome page feed always uses only the official QGIS [feed](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/62d65b23e1582c604eb3cc6c880780ff6a365b85/src/app/qgswelcomepage.cpp#L44), so even if you added your own channel I don't think it's going to be the same.

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your input. It seems it's not as easy as I imagined. I'll give it a try soon and let you know if it worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

While the code behind the news feed is open and can be reproduced, there's no way to replace the existing feed address with a new one (or add multiple feed sources). Rather, it's hard coded into the qgis source and cannot be customised (as of 3.10)